# Unable to subscribe data from Interceptor

Tags: rxjs, angular6, interceptor, angular-httpclient, rxjs6

In my `AppComponent.ts` file, I made a HTTP GET call using `HttpClient`.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, Subscriber, Unsubscribable } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
  ob: Observable<any> = null;

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {

    httpClient.get("").subscribe((response) => {
      console.log(response);
    });
  }
}
```

Then I also have an interceptor which intercepts the Http call and returns some static data (lets say cache for an example).

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpRequest } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, of } from "rxjs";

@Injectable()
export class CustomHttpInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<any> {
        return of({});
    }
}
```

However the subscription in `AppComponent.ts` file, doesn't receive any response. In fact the subscribe success or error function doesn't even gets hit.
There are no console errors either. Anyone have any idea what is going on here?

**NOTE**
I have changed the return type from `Observable<HttpEvent<any>>` to `Observable<any>` as TypeScript wasn't able to cast `Observable<{}>` to `Observable<HttpEvent<any>>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your cached response needs to be of type [`HttpResonse`](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpResponse), but to be more precise, it needs to be of type [`HttpEvent`](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpEvent), which includes the class `HttpResponse<T>`:

```
const response = new HttpResponse<object>({
  body: {},
  status: 200
})

return of(response);
```

<strike>This is kinda untested though, not sure if body needs to be a parsable json string to make it work so: `body: '{}'`, but that's for you to try. :)</strike>

Comment: Just amazing. This issue just pushed me till the edge of the top floor. I wish I could have a chance to buy you a coffee or beer :).

Comment: @Sandy Why not both? ;) Anyways, I expect you didn't have to make a parsable json string of the body, right?

Comment: Haha...yeah...both on me. And yes body can be object, it does not need to be a string.